# selecting from SQL with LEFT JOIN and multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch posts with multiple filters, my database is as below,

**"Meta" Table**

| id | meta_key | meta_value | object_name | object_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | location | new city | post | 2 |
| 1 | post_type | section | post | 2 |

[image: meta table]

**"Posts" Table**

| id | title | excerpt | description | mime _type | status | parent | post _class | dtime | sort _id | author _id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | testing |  |  |  |  | -1 | post | 2021-04-12 03:06:06 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | test post |  | some description |  | active | -1 | post | 2021-04-12 12:09:32 | 0 | 1 |

[image]

```sql
  SELECT p.id,90p.title
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN meta m
  ON p.id = m.object_id and m.object_name='post'
  WHERE m.meta_key='location' and m.meta_value='new city'
  and m.meta_key='post_type' and m.meta_value='section'
  group by p.id
```

and I tried the above SQL but trouble is I am unable to form right conditional statement, i need to get all the post which have meta key 'post type' with value 'section' and meta key 'location' with value 'new city'.

this query does work with single filter though.

```sql
  SELECT p.id,90p.title
  FROM posts p
  LEFT JOIN meta m
  ON p.id = m.object_id and m.object_name='post'
  WHERE m.meta_key='location' and m.meta_value='new city'
  group by p.id
```

Comment: Ummm. your sql includes two values for m.meta_key  "WHERE m.meta_key='location' ... and m.meta_key='post_type'"  Both conditions cannot be true in a single record, ergo, you'll receive no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT p.id, p.title
FROM posts p
JOIN meta m ON p.id = m.object_id
WHERE m.object_name='post'
  AND (m.meta_key, m.meta_value) IN ( ('location', 'new city'),
                                      ('post_type', 'section') )
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) = 2
```

Comment: that works great, with the help of your answer i also figured out how to extend this query to include taxonomy conditions as well...